# Page templates for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

Currently wordpress "pages" can have a particular page template associated with it. Can this feature also be available for custom post types ?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly set up a page template for custom post types. Give this a whirl:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Your template name
*/

// Get header
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
<?php // Query post type
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'cpt_name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php // Begin loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<section>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</section>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php // Reset
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Please add some content.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; // End loop and primary ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I figured that the post-type needs to be set to "hierarchical"

Comment: Cool. You might also want to check this out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files